# PySpark: dataframe cannot be count()

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to count the number of rows in a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`. I do that with:

```
stack_sub_jdf2.count()
```

which gives the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2540.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 23 in stage 57.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 23.3 in stage 57.0 (TID 1703, dedwfprshd056.de.neustar.com, executor 151): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
DataFrame[mid: string, maf_pid: string, true_email_pid: int, address_current_score_max: int, address_date_max: int, distance_min: double, n_did_min: bigint, n_ekeys_email_min: bigint, gender_code_max: int, is_telco_phone_cust_max: int, is_deceased_min: int, is_key_record_max: int, is_names_swapped_min: int, dob_quick_fill_min: int, dob_date_max: int, phone_date_max: int, first_name_in_email_max: int, last_name_in_email_max: int, middle_initial_in_email_max: int, is_default_zip9_max: int, confidence_score_max: int, label: int, strsplit_address_source_exploded_index1: vector, strsplit_email_source_exploded_index1: vector, address_current_code_max_index1: vector, ethnicity_max_index1: vector, er_matching_rule_max_index1: vector, age_bucket_max_index1: vector, email_verification_code_strings_index1: vector, dpc_index1: vector]
```

What should I do to troubleshoot? I'm guessing the problem is one of the columns in the dataframe and I have experimented with removing columns without luck. For example, I created a dataframe `stack_sub_jdf3` with a single variable:

```
stack_sub_jdf3.printSchema()
root
 |-- address_date_max: integer (nullable = true)
```

But I get the same result:

```
stack_sub_jdf3.count()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2824.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 69.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 69.0 (TID 1808, dedwdprshc028.de.neustar.com, executor 171): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

The same error occurs no matter which column is selected. The puzzling part is that I have run this notebook before without problems.

Comment: Somewhere the data on HDFS is not matching the schema you define for your DataFrame.

Comment: I would guess that it is some sort of import error, where you overload the `count` function with some other count (either self written or from another library). This would also explain why it worked before. Did you try to restart the interpreter/ cluster?

Comment: @Hitobat interesting hypothesis. I checked HDFS and it does not look like the underlying data has been altered.

Comment: @gaw I checked my code and it's not an import error. I restarted the interpreter. I cannot restart the cluster as it is shared with several dozen other users.

Comment: Did you execute the exact command before as well? Or maybe because of some lazy evaluation it only used the first x rows and for the `count` the code has to process every row, which could include some text instead of integer.
And did you try it with different columns to see whether the error occurs regardless of the column (e.g. try select `mid` and do a `count`)

Comment: Yes, this is mostly what I meant gaw. When you evaluate dataframe it's only when you try to process the file line with bad format that you see the error. If you only `.show(20)` or similar then maybe you do not encounter this line and so you don't see error. Also the problem will happen even if you select different column, because it happens at parse time when converting raw line to schema. Unless you are using columnar format like parquet. If you are reading something like json or csv you can do `spark.read.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").json("path")` to ignore bad records.